# how to capture close event of anytime datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, anytime

I'm using [anytime.5.1.2.js](https://www.ama3.com/anytime/) jquery plugin date and time picker. I'm trying to figure out how to capture the close event on the picker.  I was hoping to something like this:

```
$("div#newRecord #newField1").AnyTime_picker(
        {  format: "%m-%d-%Z %h:%i %p", close: function(){
            alert("picker closing");
        } } );
```

This obviously doesn't work, so how do you capture the close event?

Answer (score 0):

Any+Time™ doesn't generate any events; you'd have to modify the dismiss method (around lines 2119-2128) to generate an event yourself or inject any other code you'd like to perform.